# Keep text input focused when presenting modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a text input which should be displayed in front of all screens and should remain focused even when modals are presented. Is there anyway to do this?

Below I've managed to keep the text input above all the screens but it loses focus when the modal is presented.

[image]

```
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native'
import React from 'react'
import { Button, Text, TextInput, View } from 'react-native'
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack'
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack'

export { navigationRef } from './utils/navigation'

export function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <MyView />
      <NavigationContainer>
        <RootStackScreen />
      </NavigationContainer>
    </>
  )
}

export default App

function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text style={{ fontSize: 30 }}>This is the home screen!</Text>
      <Button onPress={() => navigation.navigate('MyModal')} title="Open Modal" />
    </View>
  )
}

function DetailsScreen() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Details</Text>
    </View>
  )
}

function ModalScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text style={{ fontSize: 30 }}>This is a modal!</Text>
      <Button onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} title="Dismiss" />
    </View>
  )
}

const RootStack = createStackNavigator()

function RootStackScreen() {
  return (
    <RootStack.Navigator>
      <RootStack.Group>
        <RootStack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <RootStack.Screen name="Details" component={DetailsScreen} />
      </RootStack.Group>
      <RootStack.Group screenOptions={{ presentation: 'modal' }}>
        <RootStack.Screen name="MyModal" component={ModalScreen} />
      </RootStack.Group>
    </RootStack.Navigator>
  )
}

function MyView() {
  return (
    <View style={{ position: 'absolute', zIndex: 999999999999999, left: 0, top: 230, right: 0 }}>
      <TextInput
        placeholder="textInput"
        autoFocus
        style={{ borderWidth: 4, width: '100%', height: 50, marginTop: 90 }}
      />
    </View>
  )
}
```

Comment: You could pass a ref of your input field to the Modal screen using forwardRefs and once modal is visible call the focus method on that input screen

Comment: Nah I don't want to do that as it will flash, I found a solution which uses keyboardHandlingEnabled = false but haven't written it up yet https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/d19987b0574975df434aa54e0f1c1fba62e7aaa3/packages/stack/src/navigators/createStackNavigator.tsx#L63